# Is Cmd+F10 that mute the Mac a built-in OS X keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, keyboard, audio, sound-volume, shortcut

I just discovered that the combination of Cmd+F10 (without any Fn key pressed) muted my mac. I wanted to know if it was a built-in keyboard shortcut as it does not appear in the System preferences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have 'Use all F1, F2 keys as standard functions' unchecked, that's the behaviour.
With or without the Cmd key, F10 mutes. Incidentally, so does Ctrl/F10 or Shift/F10.

[image]